# Why (new) people (to SharePoint SE) tag the questions with multiple [sharepoint-*] -tags? How to avoid that?

Tags: discussion, tagging, new-users

It's a two-part question of **why** and **how to avoid that**.

Why, especially new people to SharePoint SE, tag the questions so that they include often many if not all of the tags of

- [sharepoint-enterprise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-enterprise),
- [sharepoint-online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-online),
- [sharepoint-designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-designer),
- [sharepoint-foundation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-foundation),
- [sharepoint-server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-server)?

As the tags include overlapping and a sort of "either this or either that" options, it's obvious that people are not aware of what the tags mean.

How to avoid that?

Is there a way to improve the tag recommendation with better content understanding? Is it necessary to have all of the above tags as *related tags* as they are? Are e.g. [sharepoint-foundation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-foundation) and [sharepoint-enterprise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-enterprise) necessary tags to have? Here in Meta we have the *at least one of these tags is required* -feature - could we utilize it on SharePoint SE too?

The discovering of **why** should lead to a one solution for **how to avoid that**. Whether there are other ways to improve in this is something I'd like to discuss about too.

---

Why I'm asking this is because sometimes the answer is platform/version dependent and it requires an additional comment to find out to which platform/version the answer should be targeted to.

Answer (score 4):

This has some legacy to it, and I don't see them as wrong, for several reasons.

The [sharepoint-enterprise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-enterprise), has its counterpart in both [sharepoint-foundation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-foundation) and [sharepoint-standard](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-standard). In the old 2010-version of SharePoint it was possible to use the free version SharePoint foundation only. And up until today we can still use SharePoint-standard instead of a full blown SharePoint-enterprise version. So these tags definitely make sense.

[sharepoint-online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-online) has its counterpart in [sharepoint-server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-server), which makes both tags perfectly valid. There are vases where solutions can't be used (SharePoint-online) and it's very good to know before posting an answer to a question, in which environment the challenge exist.

The last one, [sharepoint-designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-designer), is useful to have if your working with workflows. Either you do a workflow with Visual Studio, Visio or SharePoint-designer. So I say we keep all of the tags mentioned in your post based on the reasoning in my answer.

Comment: Well it was only one of my questions whether all of the tags were necessary to have, but thanks for getting into that. The way you define [tag:sharepoint-online] and [tag:sharepoint-server] is indeed what bothers me - we should have only either of those present, not both. This is a *discussion topic* about the subject, but imo we have a real problem here which should be fixed, or even attempted to.

Comment: @moe I agree to that. Either it's 'online' or 'server'. Even an Azure powered SharePoint farm is 'server' imho. And often users imply 'server' without tagging questions as such. Especially when working with server code. There are no simple solution to this, and the only thing we can do is to improve tagging when we see errors...